# Docker Compose Up failing with error Exit-code 1 when calling /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run ./gradlew composeUp in my springboot project but it is failing at the start itself giving org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':{project_name}:composeUp'. I am unable to figure where it is going wrong. I am trying to run Docker using colima and also tried with Rancher.

Here is the logs

```yaml
> Task :{project_name}:composeUp FAILED
option '--no-ansi' is DEPRECATED ! Please use '--ansi' instead.
unable to get image 'fc62f61b0147a04d620568572373fa5e_{project_name}': Error response from daemon: invalid reference format
option '--no-ansi' is DEPRECATED ! Please use '--ansi' instead.
option '--no-ansi' is DEPRECATED ! Please use '--ansi' instead.
option '--no-ansi' is DEPRECATED ! Please use '--ansi' instead.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':{project_name}:composeUp'.
> Exit-code 1 when calling /usr/local/bin/docker-compose, stdout: N/A

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':{project_name}:composeUp'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exit-code 1 when calling /usr/local/bin/docker-compose, stdout: N/A
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at com.avast.gradle.dockercompose.ComposeExecutor.executeWithCustomOutput(ComposeExecutor.groovy:58)
        at com.avast.gradle.dockercompose.ComposeExecutor$executeWithCustomOutput$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.avast.gradle.dockercompose.ComposeExecutor.executeWithCustomOutputWithExitValue(ComposeExecutor.groovy:24)
```

Here is docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3.2'
services:
  wiremock:
    image: ''
    container_name: wiremock
    ports:
      - 28080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./wm_mapping:/home/wiremock/mappings:ro
    command: "--port 8080"

  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeper
    image: 'docker.io/library/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: ''
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9094:9094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "{topicName}"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INSIDE'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  postgres:
    image: ''
    container_name: {dbName}
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
    
  postgres-r2:
    image: ''
    container_name: 
    ports:
      - 25432:5432

  {project_name}:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ../../../
    container_name: {project_name}
    ports:
      - 18080:8080
      - 18082:8082
    volumes:
      - ./configs/application.yml:/application.yml:ro
      - ./configs/logging.xml:/logging.xml:ro
      - ./configs/logback-access.xml:/logback-access.xml:ro
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: 8080

    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8082/manage/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    depends_on:
      - wiremock
      - kafka
      - postgres
      - postgres-r2
    links:
      - wiremock
```

My project docker file

```yaml
FROM docker-registry/.../../openjre-11
# install {project_name}
WORKDIR app

ENV APP_NAME={project_name}-gateway

RUN ln -sf /etc/ringcentral/{project_name} config

RUN groupadd {project_name} && useradd -d / -s /sbin/nologin -M -g {project_name} {project_name}

USER {project_name}:{project_name}

COPY build/libs/*.jar ./{project_name}.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-XX:+UseContainerSupport", "-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0", "-jar", "{project_name}.jar"]
```

Please let me know if anything else is required for debugging.

Comment: What's in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Have updated the question with Dockerfile

Comment: Do you have the actual output from Compose?  Does some preprocessing happen on the Compose file before Gradle runs it?  There are a couple of issues in what you've shown (empty `image: ''` lines, `{project_name}` placeholders).